# Updating entire column with data from tuple in PostgreSQL(psycopg2)

Tags: python-2.7, psycopg2, postgresql-9.3

First of all, there is my script:

```
import psycopg2
import sys

data = ((160000,),
        (40000,),
        (75000,),
        )

def main():
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect("""host='localhost' dbname='postgres'
                                         user='postgres'""")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query = "UPDATE Planes SET Price=%s"
        cursor.executemany(query, data)
        connection.commit()

    except psycopg2.Error, e:
        if connection:
            connection.rollback()
        print 'Error:{0}'.format(e)

    finally:
        if connection:
            connection.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code works of course, but not in the way I want. It updates entire column 'Price' which is good, but it updates it only by use of the last value of 'data'(75000).

```
(1, 'Airbus', 75000, 'Public')
(2, 'Helicopter', 75000, 'Private')
(3, 'Falcon', 75000, 'Military')
```

My desire output would look like:

```
(1, 'Airbus', 160000, 'Public')
(2, 'Helicopter', 40000, 'Private')
(3, 'Falcon', 75000, 'Military')
```

Now, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Without setting up your database on my machine to debug, I can't be sure, but it appears that the query is the issue. When you execute

> UPDATE Planes SET Price=%s

I would think it is updating the entire column with the value being iterated on from your data tuple. Instead, you might need the tuple to a dictionary

`({'name':'Airbus', 'price':160000}, {'name':'Helicopter', 'price':40000}...)`

and change the query to

`"""UPDATE Planes SET Price=%(price)s WHERE Name=%(name)s"""`.

See the very bottom of [this article](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial) for a similar formulation. To check that this is indeed the issue, you could just execute the query once (`cursor.execute(query)`) and I bet you will get the full price column filled with the first value in your data tuple.